# Flutter image_gallery_saver image not-showing after saving

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to take a screenshot of my widget. For that, I am using the **RepaintBoundary** widget and to save the screenshot I use the **image_gallery_saver**  plugin. But after saving the image it **is not showing to the gallery**. How to solve this issue?

```
class Utils {
  static Future capture(GlobalKey key) async {
    DateTime now;
    now = DateTime.now();

    if (key == null) return null;

    final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
    final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final pngByte = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    // print(pngByte);

    if (!(await Permission.storage.status.isGranted)) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }

    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        Uint8List.fromList(pngByte),
        quality: 90,
        name:
            'Screeshoot_${now.day.toString()}${now.hour.toString()}${now.minute.toString()}${now.second.toString()}');
    return result;
    // return pngByte;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same in my app but I have used the GallerySaver package instead.
First I have created a method that returns me the path where the image is located and then I use GallerySaver to save the image file.

```
  Future<String> getImagePath() async {
     RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _renderQRandImageWidgetKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      final tempDirectory = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
      final String filePath = '$tempDirectory/MyQRCode.png';
      File imgFile = new File('$filePath');
      await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
      return filePath;
  }
```

```
_saveImage(String userName) async {
    try {
      String filePath = await getImagePath();
      bool isImageSaved = await GallerySaver.saveImage(filePath, albumName:"AlbumName");
      SnackBar _snackbar =  SnackBar(
        content: isImageSaved ? Text('Image saved in gallery') : Text("There was an error while saving image"),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(_snackbar);
    } catch (exception) {
      print("Error $exception");
      SnackBar _snackbar =  SnackBar(
         content: Text('Something went wrong'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(_snackbar);
    }
```